# Image in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

The image is not showing with the below code in Xamarin. Its in images folder.

```
var image = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
image.Source = "images/image1.png";
Content = image;
```

How can I fix this ?

Note : I'm using a Forms application.

Comment: `image.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("images/image1.png");`

Comment: Yes I had been tried this also, but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the images in the right folder of each platform-project.

- iOS - Place images in the Resources folder with Build Action: BundleResource
- Android - Place images in the Resources/drawable directory with Build Action: AndroidResource.
- Windows Phone / Windows / UWP - Place images in the application's
  root directory with Build Action: Content

You can find more Infos [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Local_Images).

**Edit (images in PCL-project)**

> To embed an image in a project, right-click to add new items and
>   select the image/s you wish to add. By default the image will have
>   Build Action: None; this needs to be set to Build Action:
>   EmbeddedResource.

And then load the Image `FromResource(..)`:

```
var embeddedImage = new Image { Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit };
embeddedImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("test.jpg");
```

To load images from the PCL-Project -> look at [this page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/#Embedded_Images).

Comment: In the link itself it is said you can add images to your PCL solution.

Comment: I'm trying for IOS, do I have to change the build action ? its now in default.

Comment: Please read my answer! ".. Needs to be set to Build Action: EmbeddedResource"

Comment: Yes its now showing upon I have right click to project and add file

Comment: I did it but have error, I asked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990592/type-image-not-found-error-in-xamarin-forms