# Type image not found error in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a Forms application, and have ContentPage XAML form.

I try to add an image to this Grid but
this code gives me the error `Type image not found`.
Note : I had been added this image under Recources and tried also on the root folder.

How can I fix this?

Note2: I had been by right clicked the project and had added image to project.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Text="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
  <image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" source="image2.png"></image>
  <Button Text="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML (and thus XAML) is case-sensitive, so make it `<Image>` and `</Image>`.

Like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Button Text="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
  <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="image2.png"></Image>
  <Button Text="3" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Gerald, I have did it but get this error: No Property of name source found

Comment: Ah missed that one. But it is the same problem, use a capital. I've updated the answer.